# Drop factor levels containing single observation

Tags: r, dataframe

I'd like to know if there exists a simple function (similar to drop.levels) to drop levels from a factor containing just one observation. I'll provide a reproducible example below. Until now I'm only able to store the names of the factors containing levels with just one observation, but it will be a pain to write all the code to drop the specific levels, is there some quick way to do it?

```
db0 <- data.frame(let = c(sample(letters[1:5], 99, replace = T),"z"),
                  let2 = sample(letters[6:11], 100, replace = T))

#Checking which factor has levels with only one obs
facLevels <- lapply(db0, table)
facNames <- list()
for(i in 1:length(facLevels)){
  facNames[i]<-ifelse(min(facLevels[[i]])==1, names(facLevels[i]), NA)
}
facNames <- as.character(facNames[!is.na(facNames)])
```

basically what I want to do is to drop just the z level in let.
Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "drop the z level"? Do you want to delete that row from your data? So you want to set that value to NA rather than z?

Comment: Yes, setting that row to na would be a solution since I can drop it easily then. Keep in mind I have a lot of factors with a lot of levels, and I don't know in advance which levels contain a single observation, that's why I'm opting for this approach rather than doing it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `for` loop here will set any factor level with one observation to NA then fully removes that factor level from the column by refactoring it.

```
db0 <- data.frame(let = c(sample(letters[1:5], 99, replace = T),"z"),
  let2 = sample(letters[6:11], 100, replace = T))

#Checking which factor has levels with only one obs
facLevels <- lapply(db0, table)
# make a list for each factor level that has one value
to_change <- lapply(facLevels, function(x) names(x)[x==1])

for(i in 1:ncol(db0)){
  if(length(to_change[[i]])>0){
  # set as NA
  db0[which(db0[,i] %in% to_change[[i]]),i] <- NA
  # removes the factor level, remove the code below if this is not what
  # what you wanted to do
  db0[,i] <- as.factor(db0[,i])
  }
}

> tail(db0)
     let let2
95     b    i
96     a    g
97     c    k
98     d    j
99     d    f
100 <NA>    j

> levels(db0[,i])
[1] "f" "g" "h" "i" "j" "k"
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

And in case you don't like writing for loops

```
# create a sample dataset
db0 <- data.frame(let1 = c(sample(letters[1:5], 99, replace = T),"z"),
                  let2 = sample(letters[6:11], 100, replace = T))

# calculate how many times each level is present
facLevel <- lapply(db0, table)

# drop levels which are present once
test <- sapply(facLevel, function(x) x[x != 1])

# drop rows in the original dataset where a unique level is present (do this for both columns)
db1 <- db0[rowSums(mapply(function(x, y) x %in% names(y), db0, test)) == ncol(db0), ]
```